# htaccess redirect / to cgi-bin/cgiscript.cgi not working

Tags: redirect, .htaccess, cgi

1st of all the disclaimer: this is my very first "meeting" with `.htaccess`, and I'm not a sysadm, never was, but the guy in the neighborhood, who used to set up the machine.

So now I have to set up one friends cgi ([pyblosxom](http://pyblosxom.sf.net/)) based site (on [freehostia](http://www.freehostia.com/)).

I have a directory tree like this:

```
mysite (path on freehostia is: /home/www/sitename)
|-cgi-bin
||-cgiscript.cgi
|-pybloxsom-installation
|-data
```

My problem: I want to redirect all incoming request to http://mysubdomain.freehostia.com/ (the root, and if possible http://mysubdomain.freehostia.com/data/ and http://mysubdomain.freehostia.com/pybloxsom-installation/ ) to http://mysubdomain.freehostia.com/cgi-bin/cgiscript.cgi .

Could someone explain how to do that? All my tries lead to infinite redirections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put in a .htaccess file in the mysite directory :

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://mysubdomain.freehostia.com/cgi-bin/cgiscript.cgi
RedirectMatch ^/data/ http://mysubdomain.freehostia.com/cgi-bin/cgiscript.cgi
RedirectMatch ^/pybloxsom-installation/ http://mysubdomain.freehostia.com/cgi-bin/cgiscript.cgi
```

it might not work if your hosting provider doesn't allow it.